# CORS on Meteor isn't working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, meteor, cors

Here a piece of my code at *main.js*:

```js
Meteor.startup(() => {

console.log('WEBBB',WebApp);
console.log('WEBAPP.CONNECTHANDLERS', WebApp.connectHandlers)

 WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return next();
  })

});
```

And here I'm trying to redirect to the Twitter app when there is a user click:

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello">
    <i className="fa fa-twitter-square left fa-lg"></i> Twitter
</a>
```

But I'm receiving a message with the following error on my console at the browser from the mobile inspect:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://502e070a.ngrok.io' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Here I tried to insert on my root app, on main.jsx:

```js
Meteor.startup(() => {

 // navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
 if(Meteor.isCordova) {
  console.log('Cordova ===========================');
  console.log('CORDOVA', cordova);
 }
 
 WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return next();
  })

 // Rendering the App Component
 render(<AppContainer />, document.getElementById('root'));

});
```

But I get the message saying "use" is not defined.

Comment: What are you trying to do...are you trying to reach a twitter endpoint app with your meteor app?

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to embed or load resources that don't have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set to `*`? I don't think that you're app's header is relevant since what it means it "Can this resource by accessed from another origin" and not "can this resource load other resources"

Comment: @Hackerman Yes, it's what I'm trying to do, like [this](https://output.jsbin.com/bawucufiso) code works on mobile.

Comment: So you follow the steps, you register to https://dev.twitter.com/ and create the app and all the stuff, right?

Comment: @Hackerman Yes, right!

Comment: @Guig I'm not sure, I'm gonna insert another piece of code, where I tried to insert that `setHeader`

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to embed `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello` instead of redirecting to it? Is this happening on the web or within a Cordova app?

Comment: @Guig Sorry, I don't know if I'm trying embed or redirecting, what I want to do is redirect to the Twitter app through the link I mentioned. It's happening on the mobile browser (Chrome) and with the web I get a similar error

Comment: @Guig Here the error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello. Redirect from 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello' has been blocked by CORS policy: Redirect location 'about:blank' has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests."

Comment: @Hackerman, sorry, instead of what I said I'm not trying to reach a end point of twitter, this is just like a intent, a link that redirects to a native app.